# Capturing response body - Web Client 400 bad request

Tags: java, webclient

How can I capture the response body of bad request - see img attached.

[image]

Comment: It's obviously a `WebClientResponseException` that's being thrown. Catch it as such and take a look which methods it has to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you catch this `Exception` as the `WebClientResponseException` that it obviously is, you can use a [method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClientResponseException.html#getResponseBodyAsString()) that returns the body.

```
} catch(WebClientResponseException e) {
  String responseBody = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
  //log it?
}
```